# Issue in SoftLockup on Linux Kernel 2.6.32 (RHEL 6.4)

Tags: linux, kernel

I am in need of help regarding softlockup in Linux Kernel.

I have developed a kernel driver for a Hardware, where I have to wait or loop (the time delay provided from the user application) for a specified amount of time (say example the delay time is 1 or 20 or ... minutes) to perform some tasks. I am getting softlockup message from the kernel whenever I am setting the delay time more than 1 minutes.

Is there a way to avoid the lockup messages from the kernel. I have used kernel sleep calls such as msleep, ssleep, etc also I have implemented a logic to wait for the specified time.

Any advice would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Srinivasa Raghavan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [delays - Information on the various kernel delay / sleep mechanisms](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/timers-howto.txt).
For your case:

```
    SLEEPING FOR LARGER MSECS ( 10ms+ )
        * Use msleep or possibly msleep_interruptible
```

If you are *getting softlockup message from the kernel whenever … setting the delay time more than 1 minutes* still, you could try to repeatedly wait for 1 minute.